# Is there any way to keep track of how many objects I have created with a factory function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, factory-method

Let's say I have a factory like this:

```
const itemFactory = () => {
    const itemName = ''
    const firstMethod = () => {
        // something goes here
    }

    return { itemName, firstMethod }
}
```

Is there a way I can keep track of how many items I have created with that function?
I want to include an index in the `itemName` property of each item, like this: `item0`, `item1`, `item2`, etc.

Comment: maintain a count outside of the `itemFactory` scope

Comment: The title and text are conflicting. In the title you say you want keep track of how many objects, but in the text you want the first item being named with zero ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use higher-order function to achieve that:

```
const createItemFactory = () => {
    let currentItem = 0;
    return () => {
        const itemName = 'item' + currentItem++;
        const firstMethod = () => {
            // something goes here
        }

        return { itemName, firstMethod };
    }
}
```

you can then create an `itemFactory`:

```
const itemFactory = createItemFactory();
const item0 = itemFactory(); 
console.log(item0.itemName); // item0;
const item1 = itemFactory(); 
console.log(item1.itemName); // item1;
```

[Read more about JavaScript closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)